# How to use display value and actual value in react input

Tags: html, reactjs, input, user-input

I want to set the string type display value for input and the actual value is of number type that I can use for other operations.

EX.  display value: 1,22,333 in string and actual value 122333 in number

Here is how the Input looks:

```
<input
              ref={inputRef}
              type="number"
              key={'testKey'}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              onFocus={handleOnFocus}
              onBlur={handleOnBlur}
              onKeyUp={keyUpHandler}
              onKeyDown={keyDownHandler}
              value={inputValue}
              placeholder={0}
              onClick={onclick}
              />
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

the following code solves your problem.

i have implemented the following in typescript.
you can remove the types to get the javascript version.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const NumberInput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<{
    number: number;
    formattedNumber: string;
  }>({
    number: 0,
    formattedNumber: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const value = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ""); // Remove non-digit characters
    setInputValue({ number: value, formattedNumber: formatNumber(value) });
  };

  const formatNumber = (value: string) => {
    if (value) {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN").format(parseInt(value));
    }
    return value;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue.formattedNumber}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter numbers"
        className="my-10"
      />
      <p>{inputValue.number}</p>
      <p>{inputValue.formattedNumber}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default NumberInput;
```